# How to use route_url method in ApplicationCreated event

Tags: python, pyramid

I subscribed on ApplicationCreated and I need to get same urls in my web app.
In views I can to use route_url method to get urls.
But how to get url in ApplicationCreated event?

For example in view I can use this code:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name="home")
def home(request):
    print request.route_url('home')
```

Result in console:

```
http://example.com/
```

How I can use same code in this case:

```
from pyramid.events import ApplicationCreated, subscriber

@subscriber(ApplicationCreated)
def app_start(event):
    print ????.route_url('home') # how to get access to route_url
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the problem became clear?

Comment: Yes, this is better!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's no way. You are trying to use request-required method in event where no request yet. See sourcecode [https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/**init**.py#L995](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/config/__init__.py#L995)

W/o request you can get just route object:

```py
home = app.routes_mapper.get_route('home')
print(home.path)
```

Example with custom generate URL:

```py
delete = app.routes_mapper.get_route('pyramid_sacrud_delete')
print(delete.path)  # 'admin/{table}/delete/*pk'
delete.generate({'table': 'foo', 'pk': ['id',2,'id2',3]})  # '/admin/foo/delete/id/2/id2/3'
```

Your example:

```py
from pyramid.events import ApplicationCreated, subscriber

@subscriber(ApplicationCreated)
def app_start(event):
    print event['app'].app.routes_mapper.get_route('home')
```

Comment: This method does not allow to get the host name, but thanks for the idea of how to get the path!